# Entity component system undefined symbols

Tags: c++, entity-component-system

I'm new to c++ and im trying to create a game with sfml and in this game i am trying to use an entity component system that i can use for this game and games further down the road, but when i compile i get an error and i have no idea how to fix it.

Here is my entity.hpp class:

```
#ifndef Entity_hpp
#define Entity_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Component.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Entity {

private:
    vector<unique_ptr<Component>> _components;
public:
    void Start();
    void Update();
    void Draw();

    template <typename T, typename... TArgs> T& AddComponent(TArgs... args);
    template <typename T> T& GetComponent();
};

#endif /* Entity_hpp */
```

Next is the Entity.cpp class:

```
#include "Entity.hpp"

void Entity::Update() {
    for (auto& c : _components) {
        c->Update();
    }
}

void Entity::Draw() {
    for (auto& c : _components) {
        c->Draw();
    }
}

void Entity::Start() {
    for(auto& c : _components) {
        c->Start();
    }
}

template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
T& Entity::AddComponent(TArgs... args) {
    T* component(new T(forward<T>(args)...));

    component->entity = this;

    unique_ptr<T> ptr{component};
    _components.emplace_back(move(ptr));

    return *component;
}

template <typename T> T& Entity::GetComponent() {
    T* c;

    if(find(_components.begin(), _components.end(), c) != _components.end()) {
        return &c;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

My game class where i add my components:

```
#include "Game.hpp"

void Game::Start() {
    auto& entity(_system.AddEntity());
    auto& m(entity.AddComponent<Movement>());
}

void Game::Update() {

}
```

And finally my component and its parent:

```
#ifndef MovementComponent_hpp
#define MovementComponent_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#include <Component.hpp>

class Movement : Component {

public:
    Movement() {};

    void Start() override {};
    void Update() override {};
    void Draw() override {};
};

#endif /* MovementComponent_hpp */
```

Both don't have implementation in the cpp file

```
#ifndef Component_hpp
#define Component_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Entity;

class Component {

public:
    Entity* entity{nullptr};
    virtual void Start();
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Draw();
    virtual ~Component();
};


#endif /* Component_hpp */
```

And this is the error i'm getting:

```
Ld /Users/joeywelvaadt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML-eeksqjpmpgsdomeiuuzvucxhodww/Build/Products/Debug/SFML.app/Contents/MacOS/SFML normal x86_64
    cd /Users/joeywelvaadt/Desktop/XCode/C++/SFML
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -L/Users/joeywelvaadt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML-eeksqjpmpgsdomeiuuzvucxhodww/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -F/Users/joeywelvaadt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML-eeksqjpmpgsdomeiuuzvucxhodww/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/joeywelvaadt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML-eeksqjpmpgsdomeiuuzvucxhodww/Build/Intermediates/SFML.build/Debug/SFML.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SFML.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/joeywelvaadt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML-eeksqjpmpgsdomeiuuzvucxhodww/Build/Intermediates/SFML.build/Debug/SFML.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SFML_lto.o -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -framework sfml-system -framework sfml-window -framework sfml-graphics -framework sfml-audio -framework sfml-network -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/joeywelvaadt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML-eeksqjpmpgsdomeiuuzvucxhodww/Build/Intermediates/SFML.build/Debug/SFML.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SFML_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/joeywelvaadt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML-eeksqjpmpgsdomeiuuzvucxhodww/Build/Products/Debug/SFML.app/Contents/MacOS/SFML

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Movement& Entity::AddComponent<Movement>()", referenced from:
      Game::Start() in Game.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template declaration and definition should stay in the same file (well, more or less, you can also separate them somehow by including implementation file at the end of an header, but let me simplify the matter for the sake of clarity). This is not the case for your `Entity::AddComponent` member function and thus the error.
I'd suggest you to go a bit deeper in the language if you want to use features like templating system.
That being said, move definitions of your member template functions to the `.hpp` and try again.

Comment: You are welcome. That's quite common an error for new C++ developers. ;-)
Do not forget to accept an answer on SO if it solves your problem.

Comment: I didn't know that, not only new to C++ also kind of new to stackoverflow

Comment: @DaniloWelvaadt Well, then welcome also on StackOverflow. ;-)